# Canvas.js fetch data from RESTful API

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, canvas, charts

Iam trying to fetch my data from my api by making an AJAX http request. The requested data come in JSON form. I cannot really understand in what format should data be formated in order to be read from  column charts. For example if i try to log a property of object `thedata.y` then i get undefined.If i copy my whole array instead of thedata at dataPoints then it works perfect,but not by just putting the array name. What am i doing  wrong? Thanks in advance

**Front-end script**

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
    head
        meta(charset='utf-8')
        meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        script( src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js")
        script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous")

    body
        script.
            var thedata=[];
            $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/catalog/statistics/BookingsPerResource", function (items) {
                $.each(items, function (index, value) {
                    thedata.push({
                        label: value.label,
                        y: value.y
                    })
                });
                console.log(thedata)
            })
            window.onload = function () {
                var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                    theme: "light1", // "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
                    animationEnabled: false, // change to true
                    title: {
                        text: "Basic Column Chart"
                    },
                    data: [
                        {
                            // Change type to "bar", "area", "spline", "pie",etc.
                            type: "column",
                            dataPoints: thedata
                        }
                    ]
                });

                chart.render();

            }
        div(id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;")
        h3=thedata
```

**Backend script**

```
exports.loadStats= async function (req,res,next){
      try {
          var BooksperResource = await resource.aggregate().project(
              {
                  "label":"$name",
                  y:{$cond:{if:{$isArray:"$reservation"},
                          then:{$size:"$reservation"},
                          else:0}
                  },
                  _id:0

              }
          ).limit(10)

      } catch (error){
          return next(error)
      }
      console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(BooksperResource)))
      res.send(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(BooksperResource)))

};

exports.displayStats= async function (req,res,next){
    res.render('statsDash');
}
```

**JSON response from AJAX call**

```
[
  { label: 'Sillicon Waffer Tool', y: 2 },
  { label: 'Photolithography Laboratory', y: 2 },
  { label: 'Resource', y: 1 },
  { label: '&quot; SELECT * FROM users', y: 0 }
]
```

[image: Dev tools console log]
Here is my dev tools log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution after searching a bit more. To fix that just change the structure of front end script . Should place the ajax code inside `window.onload` constructor and then inside the `$.getJSON`  MUST place the chart constructor. I know its very cringe but i do not understand why should put it like that

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
    head
        meta(charset='utf-8')
        meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        script( src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js")
        script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous")

    body
        script.

            window.onload = function () {
                var thedata = [];var  i=0;
                $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/catalog/statistics/BookingsPerResource", function (items) {
                    $.each(items, function (index, value) {
                        thedata.push({
                            label: value.label,
                            y: parseInt(value.y)
                        })
                    });

                    console.log(thedata)
                    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                        theme: "light1", // "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
                        animationEnabled: false, // change to true
                        title: {
                            text: "Basic Column Chart"
                        },
                        data: [
                            {
                                // Change type to "bar", "area", "spline", "pie",etc.
                                type: "column",
                                dataPoints: thedata
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                    chart.render();
                })
```